# Flutter align objects

Tags: flutter, user-interface, button, frontend, alignment

I am trying to align 4 objects I created myself. They have a button and a text below. I am using `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,`. But one of my texts inside one object is a bit wider than the button so it is more space between the objects where the text is outside of the button.

My object has a width default by 75. I have tried all the different MainAxisAlignments.

Can I align my object somehow only based on the button and ignore text?

I also tried to make the text disconnect to disc below the object and that did work. So the object width is wider than the rest.

Comment: Share desired UI snippet and current UI Snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try and it look way using the IntrinsicWidth widget,

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          Text('Button 1'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          Text('Button 2'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          Text('Button 3'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          Text('Button 4'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```